# Does anyone know why an Apple Push Notification development certificate would work locally, but not on my hosting server?

Tags: ssl, apple-push-notifications, pkcs#12

My client certificate seems to work locally, but not on my hosting server.

So I have a "p12" that I exported my certificate to (for push notification development). I can perform a push from both my OSX and Windows boxes (on local network). The moment I move the push and certificate out to my hosting server, I get a timeout. The Apple Push Notification Service doesn't respond at all. Why is this?

Comment: Sounds like it might be an outbound firewall port issue. Can you do a tracert to the APN service to determine if your remote server can even have external communication with the APN Service? (sorry about answer, meant to be a comment)

Comment: I am having the same problem.

What are the ports do i need to enalbe on the hosting server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [iLime](http://www.ilime.com) for doing Push Notifications. I was able to avoid the hassle setting up my own server and the integration was quick - less than an hour from start to finish.